# Oracle "not a GROUP BY expression"

Tags: sql, oracle

I getting an oracle error on my group by statements, that my group by is not an expression. This seems to work in MYSQL.

```
SELECT  pname, PNUMBER, SUM(HOURS)
FROM PROJECT, WORKS_ON w, EMPLOYEE e
WHERE w.essn=e.ssn AND pnumber=pno
GROUP BY PNUMBER;
```

Suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Try `GROUP BY PNUMBER, pname;` MySQL allows some non-standard extensions to GROUP BY.

Comment: That's because MySQL isn't respecting the ANSI standard. Every column of your `SELECT` that isn't on an aggregation function needs to be listed on the `GROUP BY`. Also, on a non-related note, you should start using explicit joins instead of the old, implict ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `GROUP BY`, the only expressions allowed in the `SELECT` clause are <sup>*</sup>

- These included on the `GROUP BY` list, and
- These using *aggregate functions*.

`PNUMBER` is OK, because it is on the `GROUP BY` list; `SUM(HOURS)` is OK because it uses `SUM` aggregator.

This leaves us with `pname`, which is neither of the two. Depending on the goals that you are trying to achieve, you need to aggregate it, add it to `GROUP BY`, or exclude from the `SELECT` list.

---

<sup>*</sup> Some RDBMS relax these rules, but generally that is how you are expected to form your queries with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Exactly that :), but with my poor english, it difficult to explain.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same like mySQL, you forgot PNAME

```
SELECT  pname, PNUMBER, SUM(HOURS)
FROM PROJECT, WORKS_ON w, EMPLOYEE e
WHERE w.essn=e.ssn AND pnumber=pno
GROUP BY PNUMBER, **PNAME**;
```